# IndexOutOfRangeException: Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection. What did I do wrong?

Tags: c#, list, visual-studio

I'm trying to create a Word Occurrence Calculator that takes in a string List and returns a WordOccurrence object List. The WordOccurrence object takes in a string word and has a count attached to it. I want each WordOccurrence object in the List to have an accurate count of how many times a word is in the string List.

I have tried a lot of different approaches. Here is the one I am working with so far. However, I get an error message about the index being out of bounds when I run the program.

```
public static List<WordOccurrence> CalculateOccurrences(List<string> input)
        {
            List<WordOccurrence> occurrences = new List<WordOccurrence>();
            HashSet<string> wordHash = new HashSet<string>();
            int index = 0;

            try
            {
                if (input == null)
                {
                    throw new ArgumentNullException("Invalid input");
                }

                foreach (string word in input)
                {
                    if(!wordHash.Add(word))
                    {
                         occurrences.Add(new WordOccurrence(word));
                    }
                    else
                    {     
                         index = occurrences.FindIndex(i => i.Word == word);
                         occurrences[index].Count++;
                    }
                }
             }
            
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);

            }
        return occurrences;
    }
    }
}
```

What is the best way to go about this? Is there a simpler method that I'm not aware of? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use the Distinct method : foreach (string word in input.Distinct())

Comment: @jdweng: Calling `Distinct` would collapse duplicates so it would only count `1` for each word. Also, this looks like a learning exercise, so suggesting an existing algorithm won't teach OP anything about implementing the algorithm.

Comment: I missing the counting.  Thanks.  var results = input.GroupBy(x => x).Select(x => new { input = x.Key, count = x.Count() }).ToList();

Comment: @thatOnePerson: Don't obsess over the "best" way. You're not going to figure that out if you're new, and if someone told you how to do it (best way or not), you wouldn't learn anything. Edit your title to include the error message because the current title is not useful. Where do you get the error? Have you tried stepping through it in the debugger?

Comment: @jdweng: There's still the other part of the point, which is that OP is meant to learn by implementing the algorithm. They're not going to learn the intended lesson by leveraging LINQ.

Comment: `if(!wordHash.Add(word))` <-- You seem to be adding `new WordOccurrence(word)` to `occurrences` when `word` _is already present in_ `wordHash`, but _not_ adding it if to `occurrences` if `word` were in fact added to `wordHash`. My guess is that `occurrences` is simply empty when you try to find the index of `word`.    See the description of the returned value in the [HashSet<T>.Add(T) docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.hashset-1.add?view=net-6.0#returns).

Comment: @madreflection Thanks for the advice, I changed my title. This is an activity for my Software Construction class. I have tried a few different algorithms, including two for loops and different if-else statements. None of them seem to work. Also, this is my first time using Visual Studio so I'm having difficulties understanding the debugging process as opposed to the IDE I'm used to.

Comment: @AstridE. That makes sense. Would it make sense if I try to add all words to HashSet and then use the if (!wordHash.Add(word)) statement to determine whether to add the word to occurrences?

Comment: @jdweng I didn't know about the Distinct method, it does sound close to what I want. Except for the counting as madreflection pointed out. However I don't understand what your second comment means. I'm new to c# having only worked with java til now.

Comment: It's a bit difficult for me to say; to be honest, I don't quite understand why you want to _add a new object_ to `occurrences`, rather than e.g. _update a counter for an object_ in `occurrences`, when you find a word that has been seen before. Could you edit your question and include your implementation of the `WordOccurrence` class? That should help us help you.

Comment: @thatOnePerson: Take a look at this: [First look at the Visual Studio Debugger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/debugger-feature-tour?view=vs-2022)

Comment: Your title should just be the exception (the exact exception message, not paraphrased). The rest is unimportant as far as the title is concerned. When someone is searching for that exception, the rest of it detracts from determining if your post could help them. Remember, it's not just about solving the problem for you, it's about building a knowledge base for the software development community, with information that helps a broader audience.

Comment: @madreflection I changed the title as you suggested. Hopefully this post can help others too. Thanks again for all your help.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you all for the comments, they helped me reach a solution that worked! I went with a foreach loop and used the Find() and Exists() method.

```
foreach (string word in input)
                {
                    if (!occurrences.Exists(i => i.Word == word))
                    {
                        occurrences.Add(new WordOccurrence(word));
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        occurrences.Find(i => i.Word == word).Count++;

                    }
                }
```

Thanks again everyone!